# What happens when HTTP POST request is interrupted by network loss?

Tags: javascript, post, upload, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive using XHR and POST (CORS) (with authentication of course). I send the file object as request body. But I just want to know what happens when after the request has been sent, the network connection is lost mid-way of file upload (partially uploaded)?

1.) Does the file get partially uploaded and is corrupted? Or Google Drive doesn't store (and list) a file unless it receives the complete file?

2.) Does GD responds with an error code in such a case?

3.) Are partial or failed uploads ignored by GD and so there is no file created on Drive at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should think in HTTP request like UDP communication.

- Client make requests
- Server reply responses

They don't really care about what happens in between. This means that once the client has done the request what happen after that is like a black box. If the server's connection get's interrupted while your request is coming the data will be corrupted, and since there is no both-ways communication the client won't know about it to re-send the request.

Now your questions:

**Does the file get partially uploaded and is corrupted? Or GoogleDrive doesn'tstore (and list) a file unless it receives the complete file?**

Yes, the file will be corrupted and you probably won't be able to open it.

**Does GD responds with an error code in such a case?**

Not exactly, if you or google are having connection issues you can't really 
  depend on that. I recommend to only assume that a file is uploaded once you receive the 200 status from GD

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. So is there any way / method to not send the details of partially uploaded file in `list` function of the GAPI? Or simply a way to know if a file is incomplete or partially uploaded (something in the app logic)?